# Три постепенно появляющиеся друг за другом строки - как сделать?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте! Мне нужно сделать на сайте (в шапке) три постепенно появляющиеся друг за другом строки, т.е. сначала первая строка постепенно появляется, потом вторая и т.д. 
У меня есть код для одного дива( я так понимаю должно быть три дива):

```
<div id="myEffect">
текст
</div>
```

стили:

```
#myEffect {    
    display: none; 
}
```

скрипт:

```
$(function(){
    $('#myEffect').fadeIn(5000);
});
```

Какую функцию нужно добавить, чтобы эти дивы появлялись друг за другом? 
Или подскажите, пожалуйста,какой-нибудь другой код, чтобы буквы как-бы постепенно писались.

Comment: @Регина, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это конечно баловство, но вот [в виде плагина](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/AJXCP/6/) ))

```
$.fn.showString = function(options){
    var el = this;
    var settings = $.extend({
        effect: 'fadeIn',
        timeDelay: 1000
    }, options);

    var countEls = el.length;
    var i = 0;
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        if(settings.effect == 'fadeIn') {
            el.eq(i).fadeIn(settings.timeDelay);
        } else if (settings.effect == 'fadeOut') {
            el.eq(i).fadeOut(settings.timeDelay);
        }
        if(i >= countEls){
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        i++;
    }, settings.timeDelay * 2);
};

// подключение
// выставить время задержки и эффект fadeIn или fadeOut
// (по умолчанию: 1000 и fadeIn)
$('.myEffect').showString({
    effect: 'fadeIn',
    timeDelay: 500
});
```

Comment: `el.eq(i)[settings.effect](settings.timeDelay);` а так будет работать?

Comment: Будет. Вы же и сами могли проверить )) Только стремновато так делать, т.к. пользователь может в одной букве ошибиться и будет лажа, а так эффект выполнится только в одном или втором случае.

Comment: допустим такую ситуацию(ошибка в одной букве):

    $('.myEffect').showString({
        effect: 'fadeln',
        timeDelay: 500
    });

в слачае с `if` искать ошибку будет очень тяжело, т.к. фактически её не будет, а если же использовать мой метод, то моментально получим `TypeError` со всеми вытекающими

Comment: Могёт быть... Значит, так, как вы предложили.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю что гуру jQuery скажут, что это код можно упростить, но он работает http://jsfiddle.net/AJXCP/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="myEffect">текст 1 текст 1 текст 1 текст 1 текст 1 текст 1 </div>
<div class="myEffect">текст 2 текст 2 текст 2 текст 2 текст 2 текст 2 </div>
<div class="myEffect">текст 3 текст 3 текст 3 текст 3 текст 3 текст 3 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.myEffect {
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".myEffect").each(function(i, el){
    if ( i == 0 ) {
        $(el).fadeIn(1000);
    }
    if ( i == 1 ) {
        $(el).delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);
    }
    $(el).delay(4000).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: почему-то не выходит...

Comment: Пример по ссылке работает, может вы что то не правильно подключаете

Comment: да ладно? а если 10 дивов будет, у вас будет 9 ифов?

    $(".myEffect").each(function(i, el){    
        $(el).delay(2000*i).fadeIn(1000);
    });

Comment: За что 3 плюса, LOL :D

Comment: @AlexWindHope, вместо того чтоб lol-ить подсказали бы как правильней сделать

Comment: невзирая на реализацию, идея хороша

Answer (score 0):

Функцию `.fadeIn()` можно вызывать так:

```
.fadeIn( [duration] [, callback] )
```

Где `callback` — функция, которая исполняется после завершения выполнения `.fadeIn()`. Следовательно, если есть три блока, то можно сделать так:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="ef1" class="myEffect">text1</div>
<div id="ef2" class="myEffect">text2</div>
<div id="ef3" class="myEffect">text3</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.myEffect{display:none}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#ef1').fadeIn(1000,function(){
    $('#ef2').fadeIn(1000,function(){
        $('#ef3').fadeIn(1000)
    })
})
```

**Демо:** [jsfiddle.net/aJrCC](http://jsfiddle.net/aJrCC/)